# AngularJS otherwise route not working?

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS redirects look like this:

```
// create the module and name it asApp
var asApp = angular.module('asApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
asApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        title: 'Home of PeppyBurro – Radical Spanish learning tips and tricks for the adventurous learner',
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        title: 'About PeppyBurro – Radical Spanish learning tips and tricks for the adventurous learner',
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the 404 page not found error
    .when('/notfound', {
        title: 'Page not found',
        templateUrl : 'pages/404.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    .otherwise('/notfound', {
        title: 'Page not found',
        templateUrl : 'pages/404.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
}]);
```

What I need is for the script to route me to 404.html when an undefined slug is entered in the URL. So if the user enters `mysite.com/#/about`, it should show him the `about.html` page. This bit works fine. But when the user enters, say, `mysite.com/#/abc`, it should show him the `404.html` page as I have defined in my `.otherwise` and `.when('/notfound')` directives. But although the `.when('/notfound')` bit is working, the `.otherwise` bit isn't. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should modify same as:

```
 .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/notfound'
  }
```

Reference [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Answer (score 2):

.when and .otherwise are two different things.

.when defines a route
.otherwise sets the default route when a route hasn't been created.
[$routeProvider.otherwise source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L236)

You have two options.

1. Take out the route path

   ```
   $routeProvider
       // ... other routes
       .otherwise({
           title: 'Page not found',
           templateUrl : 'pages/404.html',
           controller  : 'mainController'
       })
   ```
2. or define the 404 route using .when and pass the route path into .otherwise.

   ```
   $routeProvider
           // ... other routes
           .when('/notfound', {
               title: 'Page not found',
               templateUrl : 'pages/404.html',
               controller  : 'mainController'
       })
       .otherwise('/notfound');
   ```

Hope this helps!
Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

```
// As of Angular 1.3

.otherwise('/notfound')
// is short hand for
.otherwise({redirectUrl: '/notfound'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirectTo`:

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/notfound'
});
```